Follow Symbol Under Cursor Qt library symbols cannot jump to source files
After I updated Qt Creator to 12.0.2, the Follow Symbol Under Cursor Qt library symbols cannot jump to the source file. For example, if I select the method setMenuBar of QMainWindow and use Follow Symbol Under Cursor, the editor will only jump to the declaration of setMenuBar under qmainwindows.h, but not to the implementation of setMenuBar.
Do I need to do some configuration to make Qt Creator jump correctly?
I have found some methods on Google, such as adding the Qt source path in Preferences > Debugger > Source Paths Mapping. But the editor still cannot jump to the source file.
